# Auth works correctly in Firebase Web but Analytics does not work

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-analytics

The code below uses Auth and Analytics. Auth successfully generates anonymous accounts, but Analytics dashboard always show 0 for new users.
I referred to [the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web&_gl=1*3pm8wv*_up*MQ..*_ga*MTk2NzY4MjU2OS4xNzEwNjcyMTY1*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTcxMDY3MjE2NS4xLjAuMTcxMDY3MjE2NS4wLjAuMA..).

```
    private firebaseConfig = {
      // ............
    };
    
    private app = initializeApp(this.firebaseConfig);
    public analytics = getAnalytics(this.app);
    public auth = getAuth(this.app);

    logEvent(analytics, 'notification_received');

    public async loginAnonymous() {
        await signInAnonymously(this.auth)
        .then(() => {
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Some answers on StackOverflow say that it will be reflected in a few days, but I have been waiting for 3 days.
My understanding is that calling getAnalytics() counts as one user, is this correct? The dashboard doesn't work no matter how long...

Comment: As far as I know, no events are automatically logged by Firebase Authentication. Since the code you shared doesn't log any either, it seems expected that no events show up analytics.

Comment: Does it mean that new users are not counted in the `getAuth` method?
I also tried `logEvent` method but it doesnt work.